# Syntax error in COBOL program, unexpected if

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, cobol

I am coding in COBOL, and after adding the if statement listed below, I kept getting 
"
In paragraph '000-main':
Error: syntax error, unexpected IF"

```
   Identification Division.
   Program-ID. Lab2.   
  *This program will generate a statement for a single investment
  *that compounds interest monthly.
  *  It will prompt use for 3 inputs, calculate total interest
  *  earned, final balance, & entire account balance schedule.
  *  It will then display all output to the console.
   Environment Division.
   Data Division.
   Working-Storage Section.
   01  invest-amt     pic S9(9)V99.

   01  invest-error-msg      pic x(40) value "Investment "
   &     "Amount must be positive".

   01  int-rate        pic S9(2)V99.
   01  int-rate-error-msg    pic x(40) value "Annual Interest "
   &     "Rate must be positive".

   01  int-rate-final  pic 9V99999.


   01  num-months   pic S9(3).
   01  num-months-error-msg  pic x(40) value "Number of Months "
   &     "must be positive".  

   01  multiply-rate pic 9V99999.

   01  blank-line     pic x value " ".


   01  month-counter   pic 99 value 1.
   01  balance-month   pic 9(9)V99.
   01  interest-month  pic 9(9)V99.

   01  total-interest  pic 9(9)V99.
   01  final-balance   pic 9(9)V99.

   01  additional-value  pic S9(9)V99.
   01  add-value-error-msg  pic x(40) value "Additional Value "
   &     "must be positive".  
   01  Q           pic 9(3).
   01  R           pic 9(3).
   01  months-in-year pic 9(2) Value 12.


   Procedure Division.
   000-main.
       perform 100-initialize

       perform until invest-amt >=0 
          display invest-error-msg
          perform 200-input
       end-perform

       perform 210-input-rate

       perform until int-rate >=0
          display int-rate-error-msg
          perform 210-input-rate
       end-perform

       perform 220-input-month

       perform until num-months >=0
          display num-months-error-msg
          perform 220-input-month
       end-perform

       perform 230-input-additional-value

       perform until additional-value >=0
          display add-value-error-msg
          perform 230-input-additional-value
       end-perform

       perform 300-print-words

       perform 400-process-interest
       perform 310-print-values
       display blank-line

       perform until month-counter = num-months
          add 1 to month-counter

          Divide month-counter By months-in-year Giving Q Remainder R
```

Everything was compiling fine up until I added the if statement below.

```
          if ( (num-months> months-in-year) & (R=0))
             Add additional-value to balance-month

          multiply month-counter by months-in-year 

          add interest-month to balance-month rounded
          perform 400-process-interest
          perform 310-print-values
          display blank-line
       end-perform
```

Comment: For compilers that support it, `&` is a concatenation operator. You can't just make up syntax. Get hold of a manual for your compiler. Just to mention, you make your code look really sloppy by not bounding symbols with spaces.

Comment: Your `Divide` extends beyond a valid column for fixed-format COBOL. That and the `&` in your `IF` are the problems, although it seems there is some compiler which supports `&` in an IF. From the indentation you are expecting an `END-IF``but since it is optional, it is not a compile error (though almost certainly a logic error).

Answer (score 3):

My compiler complained of a missing `end-if` and didn't like <kbd>&</kbd>. I fixed the <kbd>&</kbd> problems in the obvious way.

Inserting `end-if` after `Add additional-value to balance-month` seemed to produce a clean compile. Naturally, the final `end-perform` needed a full stop

end-perform<kbd>.</kbd>

I suspect your compiler is producing that message because your `if` statement is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not compile your code.

You are missing the END-IF for your IF statement.
You should also put a "STOP RUN." in your program.
For example...

```
 perform until month-counter = num-months
      add 1 to month-counter

      Divide month-counter By months-in-year Giving Q Remainder R
      if ( (num-months> months-in-year) & (R=0))
         Add additional-value to balance-month
      end-if ******* <- YOU NEED THIS
      multiply month-counter by months-in-year 

      add interest-month to balance-month rounded
      perform 400-process-interest
      perform 310-print-values
      display blank-line
   end-perform
  STOP RUN. *** <- THIS WOULD BE NICE AS WELL.
```

Comment: What compiler did you use that supports `&` for and? It is non-standard. What did you compile as, fixed, or free-format? Since you can't see the whole program, what makes you think a `STOP RUN` is missing? The `END-IF` is optional, so although it probably wants one, from the indentation, it is not causing the compile error.